# Undefined property: stdClass::$showFooterWidgetOne

Tags: laravel

[image]

has('showFooterWidgetOne') ? ' has-error' : ''); ?>">

```
        <label>Footer Widget 1 </label>

        <div class="input-group">

            <div class="input-group-addon">

                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>

            </div>



            <select name="showFooterWidgetOne" class="form-control">

                <!----------- error part ----------->
                <option value="Yes" <?php if($SRow->showFooterWidgetOne == 'Yes'): echo 'selected'; endif;?>>Yes</option>

                <option value="No" <?php if($SRow->showFooterWidgetOne == 'No'): echo 'selected'; endif;?>>No</option>

            </select>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- /.form-group -->
```

I'm noob in laravel and i got some work accidently in laravel. also get that issue when try add some new field in form but when i added field then i start getting this error showing in image. Please help me to get out from this issue. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Sounds like `$SRow`  does not contain such a property. Also, please have a look at a Blade tutorial. You should not use `<?php` within a template

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $Srow is not a Laravel model. Try to access the showFooterWidgetOne property like an array. Change this line `<?php if($SRow->showFooterWidgetOne == 'Yes')` to `@php if($SRow['showFooterWidgetOne'] == 'Yes') ... @endphp`.

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array.. now its showing this error

Comment: @Ash Can you make a dump og you $SRow var and share it for us, please? `@dd($SRow);` Then we will find out the problem :-)

Comment: @Ash And you found the problem?

Comment: not yet please tell me og means ???

Comment: @Ash what do you mean with `og means`?